# How do I find the PIN for a Connect Cluj public transport smartcard?

Tags: public-transport, romania

I bought a bus ticket from one of the many ticket machines around Cluj Napoca - and it came on a Connect Cluj smartcard - and now trying to top the card up to use again, however after clicking reload card I am asked for a PIN. What is this PIN and how do I find it? It is not printed on the receipt or displayed when purchasing the card?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All cards start with the pin "1234" by default - so you can use that to top up your card. The pin number can be changed from the default under the consult card option on the same ticket machines.

This information is on the operators website at https://ctpcj.ro/index.php/ro/ticketing/instructiuni-pentru-achizitionarea-titlurilor-de-calatorie-de-la-automate and https://ctpcj.ro/index.php/ro/ticketing/instructiuni-de-folosire-a-automatului/421 - though at time of writing neither seems to have an English version. And was certainly the case earlier this evening (October 2022).